# Error 500 when request POST - Next JS 13 app directory

Tags: reactjs, rest, next.js

I creating a simple route to create a user.
When I send the request I get error : `500 Internal Server Error`.

The logs shows :

```
 error TypeError: res.status is not a function
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/register/route.ts:33:20)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37)
```

I have my route in `app/api/register/route.ts`
And my component calling the route in `app/components/Connextion.tsx`

Here is my component :

```
function Connexion() {
    const [hasAccount, setHasAccount] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const register = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            if (password !== confirmPassword) Notifier("Passwords do not match", "error");

            await axios.post("/api/register", {
                email,
                password,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }, [email, password, confirmPassword]);

    return (
[...]
```

And my route :

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";

export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        if (req.method !== "POST") return res.status(405).end();
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const existingUser = await prismadb.user.findUnique({
            where: {
                email,
            },
        });

        if (existingUser) return res.status(422).json({ error: "E-mail already exists. Login instead." });

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

        const user = await prismadb.user.create({
            data: {
                email,
                hashedPassword,
                image: "",
                emailVerified: new Date(),
            },
        });

        return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: `Something went wrong: ${error}` });
    }
};
```

The request on POSTMAN returns the same error.

Where is my mistake ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In next 13 you can use NextResponse in route handlers:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
  // Here your logic
          const user = await prismadb.user.create({
            data: {
                email,
                hashedPassword,
                image: "",
                emailVerified: new Date(),
            },
        });
 
  return NextResponse.json({ user }, {status: 200})
}
```

Comment: So we have to use NextResponse ? We can't use Nodejs res and req ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem and solved it by doing this:
instead of using NextApiRequest and NextApiResponse u should use NextRequest and NextResponse. And change "const { email, password } = req.body;"
to const { email, password } = await req.json();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).